# How can an android app prove its identity to web server?

Tags: android

Let's say, I have a backend server and an android app. I want to make sure that only my android app can access to my server. If a request that is not from my app is sent to my server, the server should reject the request. Even if someone somehow get the api url and make a request, the request must be rejected. How can I achieve that? I don't need the detail. If I get only the name of the methodologies, it would help me a lot.

Comment: You could add the android device id to the server and send that in with your API request.  Unless you are just trying to do a webview.

Comment: @KristyWelsh The app is gonna installed on a lot of users' devices. So filtering by ip address is not an option in this case.

Comment: Even if it is not designed to prove an app's identity the only current approach is using Android SafetyNet. As long as the device is not rooted undetected and the returned app published certificate hash (returned by Android SafetyNet) matches the chance is quite good that the app is genuine. Of course that excludes a lot of devices: rooted devices, custom ROMS, and recent Huawei devices.